# dynamic image link in php (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, image, dynamic

I am building a site on my test server, that will eventually be migrated to its own domain when it is finished.
For this reason i am trying to find a way to dynamically link to certain images, so i do not have to change the links when i move the site.

Is there a way to use php to dynamically pull the site url (of whatever domain the link is currently on) and then set the relative path to the image file?

I tried the following code without success:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/fft/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/rogue-fitness-logo.jpg">
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you calling this line of code? In a template/theme page?

Comment: in a text widget.
I seem to have found my own answer, though.
I simply did the standard relative path: 
{./subfolder/path/to.image/.jpg} and it appears to be working now.

Comment: If you are placing this line of code in a text widget, you are trying to run PHP in an HTML widget. This can not be done. You would have to create a PHP file and include it on the page that is being loaded.

Comment: I totally spaced on that one. I forgot php doesnt work in the standard  text widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run php in the WordPress editor. You can enable php execution in the editor, though it's not a good idea if other users will be editing. You can execute php, of course, in template and theme files.

And you can execute php in a widget if you use the [WordPress › PHP Code Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/) plugin.

But relative paths will work in the html editors and continue to work in most cases. See [Relative URLs in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187437/relative-urls-in-wordpress)

But you can allow the test server or localhost domains to be inserted by the editor by WordPress, and then use [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to migrate the URLs. That tool correctly serializes/reserializes data in the database, so there is no breakage.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I simply did the standard relative path: [./subfolder/path/to/image.jpg] and it appears to be working now.
I totally spaced on that one. I forgot php doesn't work in the standard text widgets.