# Wordpress - 2 domains to point same directory

Tags: wordpress

Need some expertise help to use 2 domain names for my WordPress website.

If user type www.example.com or www.example.com.sg, it have to direct to same web page. As WordPress stores values of links with default URL, its possible to use different domains to point same directory?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you may run into Search Engine Penalty of duplicate content as it is not recommended by SEO standards to have same content on multiple paths.

As a first step you need to define `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants conditionally in our WordPress root `index.php` (backup it in safe place as future updates may overwrite it)

```
if('www.example.com' == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
    define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
} else if('www.example.com.sg' == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    define('WP_HOME','http://example.com.sg');
    define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com.sg');
}
```

Put it very first before following code:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
```

so dynamic urls will work properly, for absolute url inside content (throgh backend RTE editor), you may need to use some plugin which provide such feature, here are some interesting links:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-relative-content/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/abt-relative-urls/
[Relative URLs in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187437/relative-urls-in-wordpress)

Comment: Hi Dharman, Thanks for your comments. I feel later part search engine duplicate duplicate content rule will penalised my client. is it possible to use "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com.sg/">" code to redirect if "example.com" to "example.com.sg"?