# Wordpress - how to change absolute links to relative links

Tags: php, wordpress

I've just completed my first Wordpress site for a client and sent the files via FTP transfer to their server. I've just received the following comment back -

"*...a few things don’t seem to be displaying properly, or linking correctly… It looks as though they’ve used absolute links instead of relative ones, so certain things aren’t pulling through properly...*"

I didn't even realise this would be an issue as I assumed all the links would require changing anyway. Is there a code function that can go in the `functions.php` file to amend this? I've seen that there is a `wp_make_link_relative` and the following filters -

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'wp_make_link_relative' );       // Normal post link
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wp_make_link_relative' );  // Custom post type link
add_filter( 'page_link', 'wp_make_link_relative' );       // Page link
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wp_make_link_relative' ); // Attachment link
add_filter( 'get_shortlink', 'wp_make_link_relative' );   // Shortlink
```

Should I apply these to my functions.php file? Will that fix everything or do I need to apply anything else, like a plugin?

Comment: The absolute links, are they in your theme files or in posts' content stored in DB?

Comment: @Junaid They're definitely in the theme files that I've built - there's no content as such stored at this point to my knowledge.

Comment: This sounds like another question I just answered for you with changing links to relative URLs...

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone This was a 'wider' issue which I've now resolved. The background-image issue is, I guess, an offshoot. It's my first WP client job and I've made a few schoolboy errors along the way.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead no problem and glad you got it solved, just wanted to see if I could help over here too... If you ever want any help let me know. I've been working with WordPress for longer than I care to remember!

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone Thanks Peter, I may take you up on that. Just trying to finish off first client job, hoping for lots more.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve relative links for your images/icons, JS and CSS assets do the following.

I suppose you've your assets layed out like this,

```
- theme-name
- - assets
- - - images
- - - css
- - - js
```

So, to access a file named `scripts.js` in your `js` directory, use the following code to link to it

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js'
```

It'll return the following URL

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/assets/js/scripts.js
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best solution, but it works.

Add this constant in **index.php**

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', '/wp-content');
```

Topic about this solution is there: [Relative URLs in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187437/relative-urls-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

There are several places where URLs get defined. The above lines should work for most of them, but not media or any custom API work. Also, WordPress SEO plugins like Yoast create absolute URLs, which can negatively impact your SEO if you edit them in the database.

If they say "things don't seem to be displaying properly..." they may mean assets. For that, go to

> Settings > Media > Full URL path to files and change it to
> **/wp-content/uploads.**

For absolute URLs in JS files, in functions.php create a function like this:

```
function create_root_url() {

wp_localize_script( '<your-main-js-bundle>', 'any-variable-name', array(
    'root_url' => get_site_url()
  ));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'create_root_url' );
```

Then in your JS file, change your hard-coded url to:

```
const endpoint = `${any-variable-name.root_url}/wp-json/api...`;
```

or whatever your purpose may be.