# How to link images and pages in wordpress pages?

Tags: wordpress, url

So, in the WordPress page, I need to link the pdf in wp-contents so I linked it with the relative URL as `href="/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/test.pdf"`

when I click it since my root in localhost is `localhost/test` it takes me to `localhost/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/test.pdf` (which doesn't serve the file). However, I don't think it'll be an issue in the server. Still, I want to know if this is the correct way?

Also, so I'm in page `localhost/test/page22` Now on the page, I have an anchor tag as `href="/page23"` it takes me to `page23` correctly, but when I'm in a different sub page say `localhost/test/page/page2` now, the link takes me to `localhost/test/page/page23` which is not correct as it should be `localhost/test/page23`. How can I solve these issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative URLs in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187437/relative-urls-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress provides functions for getting the URL of resources you should use these instead of having your code generate the URL. In this case you should call [wp_get_attachment_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)().