# How to remove hardcoded domain name from WordPress links?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress loads all assets and links with an absolute URL including the domain name (e.g. `<img src="https://example.com/cat.png">`).

How to **NOT** include the domain name?

I tried [editing the `WP_CONTENT_URL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187437/relative-urls-in-wordpress) and updating `WP_SITEURL`/`WP_HOME` with no success.

Is there a simple way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by simply WordPress theme URL function `get_template_directory_uri()`. See the below link.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/

It will give a full path to the WordPress theme. If your image path is like this

> \wp-content\themes\your-theme\assets\images\image.jpg

then you can get that image path like below.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/image.jpg'; ?>">
```

Comment: The problem is that these links are generated automatically by WordPress. I would have to look into the theme's source code for every link and replace with the proposed function.

Is there an easier alternative?

Comment: @merc1er yes. you have to check that in your all files and database and if that exists in the files then keep the URL as I told.

Comment: The question was "is there an easier alternative?"

Comment: @merc1er That is the easier alternative. Visit your database and find that string/modify it. Then repeat it with your code base. OR you can manually visit the WP admin side and manually modify everything one by one.