# How to allow relative links in wordpress "insert link" functionality

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress, if I link text using a relative link path (ie: simply making the link "contact/", it automatically converts it to a full path link, making it https://contact

Is there a way to allow this type of link?  I've tried some relative url filters and plugins and they work fine for things like image paths, head assets, etc, but don't affect internal links.

We've working on a big site for a national fitness studio and each city will have it's own section of about 30 pages, and then we'll be cloning a full city and updating content where needed.

So there's domain.com/chicago
And then inside we have /chicago/yoga, /chicago/yoga/classes, /chicago/yoga/instructors.   lots of links to and from those nested pages

When that's all cloned to /new-york, if those links were relative, "yoga/classes", all of the links would already be set up on the cloned pages, instead of having to go in and change every link instance from chicago to new-york

Hope that make sense, hard to explain :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That should be what you're looking for:

---

### wp_make_link_relative();

> `wp_make_link_relative( string $link )`.
> Convert full URL paths to absolute paths.

*Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_make_link_relative/*

```
wp_make_link_relative( get_permalink() );
```

---

Comment: Not quite right...

Those are still absolute urls.  I basically want a way to make the Insert/Edit link to accept urls exactly as I enter them.  So if I set the link to just "contact", the link is just "contact", and not converted to https://contact

That way if I'm in /chicago, it will go to /chicago/contact, and in /newyork it will go to /newyowkr/contact

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187437/relative-urls-in-wordpress ?

Comment: Yeah, checked that.  Turns out this may be an issue with the Elementor plugin.  In the normal page editor I can just set the link and then go back to remove the leader slash and it will keep it as that.  Elementor seems to be forcing the full path links.