# How can I use global regex to replace all instances of something without breaking other Javascript functions?

Tags: html, jquery, dom, text, replace

I'm trying to replace all instances of `http:///` on my website with `/` using global regex like this:

`$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/http:\/\/\//g,'/'));`

It works well, but unfortunately this somehow breaks all the other Javascript-bound events and functions I have on my website.

Does someone know of a way to achieve the same without breaking the other functions?

I tried to find other ways of using global regex but I'm guessing this somehow messes with the DOM, so not sure how to fix this.

Thank you!

EDIT: To clarify, Airtable is my headless CMS. Data for the website is pulled from Airtable. Airtable has rich-text fields (where my client writes his page content), but the Airtable API automatically prefixes `http://` to any links. Any relative links, for example `/about-us`, are turned into `http:///about-us` because of this. So the issue is with links inside of `href` attributes. Not sure if this context is relevant, but I thought I’d add it anyway.

Comment: Will a search and replace using your code editor not work?

Comment: You need to limit the scope: Only replace matches in, say, `src` and `href` attributes.

Comment: No this data is automatically pulled from Airtable when the site is published. The issue is that Airtable prefixes `http://` to any link, so relative links starting with `/`are inserted as `http:///`

Comment: replacing HTML with innerHTML is like erasing a whitebord. It writes everything again so any event listeners that are bound are removed. So the solution is not to use innerHTML

Comment: So is this links? images? what has the `http:///`??

Comment: It's only links. Data is pulled from Airtable. When I add a relative link (for example `/about-us`) to rich text in Airtable, for some reason their API automatically prefixes `http://` to any link, so it becomes `http:///about-us` inside the `href` on my published website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chnaging the innerHTML removes all the event listeners bound. So I would just alter the content that has the issues directly. If it is links, select all the links with the problem and replace them attribute.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="http:///"]').forEach(link => link.href = link.href.substr(7))
```

```html
<a href="http:///example1">test</a>
<a href="http:///example2">test</a>
<a href="http:///example3">test</a>
<a href="http:///example4">test</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! Unimportant question, do you know why a forward-slash is appended to each link? Not a problem, but would like to understand the solution :)

Comment: unsure what framework you are using so hard to guess what code you are using that is doing it. If wordpress: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187437/relative-urls-in-wordpress

Comment: I meant in your code, the examples you gave are turned into `example/` instead of `example`

Comment: `/example` and `/example/` are the same thing....